# Can't send mail in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.7

I have a form in which I get **to**, **from**, **subject** and **message** as input. On submit, it sends an email to the specified client (**to**).

I created a **Mailable** and in controller doing something like

```php
Mail::to($request['to'])->send(new SendMail($request['from'], $request['subject'], $request['message']));
```

Here is my Mailable `_constructor`

```php
public function __construct($from, $sub, $msg)
{
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->sub = $sub;
        $this->msg = $msg;
}
```

Here is the build method

```php
 public function build()
 {
          return $this->from($address = $this->from, $name='Company Support')
                      ->subject($this->sub)
                      ->view('emails.sendmail');
 }
```

In my **log** file I am getting an error like

> [] operator not supported for strings {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   [] operator not supported for strings at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shopvel_\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php:582)
>   ....

I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I had tried many solutions but it didn't work. For example, removing **from** in **build** method then it shows

> local.ERROR: Illegal string offset 'address' {"exception":"[object]
>   (ErrorException(code: 0): Illegal string offset 'address' at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shopvel_\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php:318)

**EDIT 1:** Here is my email view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Mail</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{ $msg }}
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 2:** When I pass two variables in the `constructor` method it is working fine like

```php
Mail::to($request['to'])->send(new SendMail($request['from'], $request()->all()));
```

**Is there any limit for passing the variable in the constructor method??**

(I don't think so since constructor can take any number of variables)

Comment: in first line of your code the `request` method is a collection, not an array so you could use it like this `$request->from` not `$request['from']`

Comment: @Joseph but `$request['from']` and `$request->from` both returns a string like `support@website.com`

Comment: maybe the problem 
`return $this->from($address = $this->from, $name='Company Support')`
edit it to
`return $this->from($this->from, 'Company Support')`

Comment: Already tried that but it didn't work

Comment: could you edit your post and add your mail view ?!

Comment: do you use laravelcollective to generate form ?!

Comment: No that's a simple form with HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198766/discussion-between-joseph-and-stukedcoder).

Comment: You are not including "msg" when you send the datas to the view, why is that so??

Comment: @PawanAcharya as in the docs **the variables declared in the constructor are available in the view automatically**.

Answer (score 5):

The $from parameter in your constructor is clashing with (and overwriting) the $from public property in the Mailable class.

```
public function __construct($from, $sub, $msg)
```

Change it to something like this...

```
public function __construct($fromAddress, $sub, $msg)
```

and it will work fine